# thumbnailLink contains an invalid url

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm creating an integration between my app and dropbox, but I can't figure out why the link inside of the thumbnailLink field is incorrect and not accessible.

I'm using the Drop-in/Chooser api.
If I try to open the link in the thumbnailLink field the dropbox api returning "error not found".

Someone never happened the same problem?

Comment: So you have a sample link you can share? How are you trying to download from the link? The full error response may be useful too.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201543525-thumbnailLink-contains-an-invalid-url ]

Comment: you can use this example to understand the problem. 

http://codepen.io/kbjohnson90/pen/qnlkz 

the preview of the image it's not show correctly because the link inside the thumbnailLink is not valid.